# How do I create a package protected constructor in Python?

Tags: python, oop, constructor

I'd like to create a factory pattern in Python, where one class has some configuration, and knows how to build another class' object (or several classes) on demand.  To make this complete, I would like to prevent the created class from being created outside of the factory.  In Java, I would put both in the same package, and make the class' constructor package protected.

For regular method names or variables, one can follow the Python convention and use single or double underscores ("_foo" or "__foo").  Is there a way to do something like that for a constructor?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment from Wim, one can name the class of the object to be created starting with a single or double underscore.  This way it is clear that the constructor is private, and should not be called directly.

Comment: Not sure why this is at zero - this seems like a good, pythonic way to make a class that is ok to inherit from but should not be instantiated.  Maybe I would change this answer to say "This way it is clear that the constructor is _protected_, and should only be called by derived classes").

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The Python mentality is often summed up as "we're all grown-ups here"; that is, you can't stop people calling methods, changing attributes, instantiating classes, and so on. Instead, you should make an obvious way to construct an instance of your class and then assume that it will be used.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother, it's not the Python way.

The preferred solution is to simply document which constructor or factory method clients are supposed to call, and not worry too much about public/private (which doesn't mean much in Python anyway; everything is essentially public-in-code.)

Answer (score 2):

The convention in Python is to **prefix the name of internal things** (members or classes) **with an underscore**. There is no way to enforce limited access, but the underscore serves as a signal that "you shouldn't be touching this".

From the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html):

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.

Comment: And `__double_underscore` names are actually mangled, which doesn't enforce any security but causes problems.

Comment: This can't be used on a constructor though, can it?

Comment: @oneself: you call the constructor by using the class name, and you can put an underscore in the class name.